# is it possible to get ViewData collection length

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

Because i have to introduce some conditional  `if` `else` statement in entire code base on collection index number

### controller passing :

```
 ViewData["productSl_1"] = appDataContext.Products.ToList();
```

### view :

```
@{var viewDataProd = ViewData["productSl_1"] as IEnumerable<Nazmulkp.Models.Product>;}
    @for (var i = 0; i < viewDataProd.length; i++) {
            {

            }
```

compile time error :

> does not contain a definition for 'length' and no extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'length'

Comment: It needs to be `as List<Nazmulkp.Models.Product>` and `@for (var i = 0; i < viewDataProd.Count; i++) {` But why are you not using the code in Shyju's answer to your other question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Cast it to IList and use Count:

```
ViewData["productSl_1"] = appDataContext.Products.ToList();
@{ var viewDataProd = ViewData["productSl_1"] as IList<Nazmulkp.Models.Product>;}
    @for (var i = 0; i < viewDataProd.Count; i++) {
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use view data. I would pass the whole list as is to the view.

Your action method would look something like this. Get the products from your data source and send this list directly to the view:

```
// Make use of the using directive
using Nazmulkp.Models;

public ActionResult Index()
{
     // Get you products from your data source
     // I used a repository, but you can use any other way to get your data
     List<Product> products = productRepository.GetAll();

     return View(products);
}
```

Setup your view to receive a list of products. Loop through these products using the `for loop` and not the `foreach loop`. You now have access to an index, namely `i`, and then you can access individual products in the list using this index, for example:

```
@Model[i].Name
@Model[i].Description
@Model[i].Price
```

Your view could look like this:

```
@model List<Nazmulkp.Models.Product>

@for (i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
     <div>@Model[i].Name</div>
}
```

If you need to make use of an `if else statement` in the `for loop` then it will look something like this:

```
@model List<Nazmulkp.Models.Product>

@for (i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
     if (i == 1)
     {
         <div>@Model[i].Name</div>
     }
     else
     {
         <div>Do something else</div>
     }
}
```

Comment: this is basic idea to pass the whole list as is to the view. this response not help me .thank you

Comment: Start learning ASP.NET MVC best practices as soon as possible.

Comment: thank you for your guideline. i will be appreciate if you provide me any link.